# where to put my js for tipsy - jquery tooltip

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, jquery-plugins

So I've downloaded and included in my stylesheets and javascript files "tipsy.css" and "jquery.tipsy". I added the image "tipsy.gif" and modified it's path.
I put in my application.js the following

```
$(window).load(function () {
   $('#example-1').tipsy();
});
```

And I put this line in my view:

```
<a id='example-1' href='#' title='Hello World'>Hover over me</a>
```

When I hover over it no tipsy magic comes to work. Only the standard on hover title. What am I doing wrong here?

I am using ruby on rails and have included this in my stylesheets and js:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application','tipsy'%>
<%= javascript_include_tag "application", "jquery", "jquery.tipsy"%>
```

I've tried many things from changing my window.load function and changing classes of my element and done a lot of googling but i just can't find the answer what is wrong here.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I had a conflict with prototype library. Now it works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "application", "jquery", "jquery.tipsy"%>
```

to:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "jquery", "jquery.tipsy", "application" %>
```

I don't know Ruby on rails and the `javascript_include_tag` but I assume you where loading application.js before jQuery and tipsy where available.

Comment: Might be a multipart problem, check if all resources are loaded properly (stylesheet, images, js in right order, etc)

Answer (score 2):

The tipsy source comes partitioned into the correct folders. You put the files in stylesheets/ into public/stylesheets, and so on. Then I would add `javascript_include_tag "jquery.tipsy"`. Make sure to view the source to make sure that it's loading it, if not, then you have a name/path mismatch.

By the way, make sure you have installed the [ujs handler](https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs) for jQuery, otherwise, you're still using the rails-default of prototype, so that means that your references to the `$` function are actually being routed to prototype and not jQuery.

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Object [object DOMWindow] has no method 'load'. I get this error in chrome dev tools. It references: $(window).load(function () {
   $('#example-1').tipsy();
});  Should I do it some other way? And yes I have jQuery.noConflict(); written and my "jquery.tipsy" gets loaded. And thank you for answering.