# twipsy js not working on rails project

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3

Let me first say I am very unfamiliar with javascript, but I am trying use twitter's twipsy (http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html), their take on jQuery's tipsy.

Here are all the scripts that are getting loaded:

```
<script src="/javascripts/effects.js?1314051118" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/javascripts/dragdrop.js?1314051118" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/javascripts/controls.js?1314051118" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/javascripts/rails.js?1314051118" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/javascripts/bootstrap-twipsy.js?1326303918" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/javascripts/application.js?1314051118" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

As you can see, bootstrap-twipsy.js is getting loaded.

Then on an index.html.erb page I am trying the following code:

```
<a href="#" id="example" rel='twipsy' title='Some title text'>text</a>

<script>
  $(function() {
    $('#example').twipsy();
    $("a[rel=twipsy]").twipsy({
      live: true
    });
  })
</script>
```

I get nothing. The reason I have the ('#example').twipsy in there is that I was just trying to call it two different ways, but neither worked. Does anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

In a similar question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4916501/where-to-put-my-js-for-tipsy-jquery-tooltip) someone found that their prototype.js was causing conflicts, but I've removed that and I still got nothing.

Comment: For what it's worth, I just installed `jquery-rails` which wiped out all the prototype stuff in favor of jquery, but I'm still not getting a response from twipsy.

Comment: Ah, actually that did fix it, just needed to restart the ole server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Installing [jquery-rails](https://github.com/indirect/jquery-rails) did the trick